# Hide Sherlock ActionBar Icon (XML)

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock

I've been searching around and trying to find a way to hide the icon on the actionbar in my app using XML. This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    <style name="Theme.Planable" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_planable</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Planable</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Planable</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Planable</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Planable</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Planable</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Planable</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_planable</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_planable</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Planable</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Planable" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_planable</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_planable</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_planable</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Planable</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: is there an option for `<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>` without android namespace? I mean like this `<item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>`. This could be the reason, because for every attribute inside your style definition you should add two items - for android and sherlock namespaces.

Comment: You mean adding both? I've tried to add both <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> and <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>